# Why searching for relatedVideos not returning nextPageToken for pagination?Any help is appreciated

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When using [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&relatedToVideoId=HZsRjrYW-lk&maxResults=10&key=${key}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&relatedToVideoId=HZsRjrYW-lk&maxResults=10&key=$%7Bkey%7D) the response doesnt contain nextPageToken even though the number of results are more than the no of items returns

I tried increasing the maxResults to check if there are more results and using maxResults for pagination but i dont think its the best way to get 40 results and return last 10 result for example :-
1st page :- currentPage = 0 ;maxResult=currentPage+10;return items[maxResult-10]---items[maxResult]
so for 1st page currenPage = 0 ,maxResult = 10,return : items[0]--items[10]

2nd page :- currentPage = 10 ;maxResutl = currentPage+10 ;return items[maxResult-10]--items[maxResult]
so for 2nd page currenPage = 10 ;maxResult = 20 ;retrn items[10]--items[20]
..and so on

but the problem is that i need to get all the vidoes and then cut the part i dont need

Comment: The part *to get 40 results and return last 10 result for example... and so on* is unclear to me, maybe it's due to the absence of new lines, please better format what you have in mind.

Comment: Anyway the absence of `nextPageToken` looks like a bug, have a look to [the YouTube Data API v3 issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) and post a new one if it hasn't already been reported. If it hasn't been reported, please copy here the issue you created there.